# Eloquent build where query from array

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

So I'm trying to prepare an Eloquent query from data in an associative array:

```
/* This works */
$this
    ->where("email", "me@gmail.com")
    ->where("is_active", 1)
    ->update($params);

/* This doesn't work */
$where = [
    'email' => "me@gmail.com",
    'is_active' => 1
];
foreach ($where as $k => $v) {
    $this->where("{$k}", "{$v}");
}
$this->update($params);
```

Am I missing something?
Any help appreciated.

Edit: The query does not update the entity in the database.

Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish): 4.18.0-17-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.30.2
Laradock, Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Why is `$k` and `$v` wrapped in quotes?

Comment: @dharman to show that I tried several versions of this during testing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because every `$this->where()` instantiates a new query builder, but never executes it.

This works:

```
$where = [
    'email' => "me@gmail.com",
    'is_active' => 1
];

$query = $this->newQuery();

foreach ($where as $k => $v) {
    $query->where("{$k}", "{$v}");
}

$query->update($params);
```

You can also use `where()` with an array:

```
$this->where($where)->update($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me why you need this. But there's no reason to loop over, you can simply add the array to the where method.

```
$this->where([
    'email' => "me@gmail.com",
    'is_active' => 1
])->update();
```